# DIV show and hide with jumping to next when click on link

Tags: html, css, show-hide, paging

I'm using `css` & `html` to show/hide a few div's. 
(http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x8HmQ/2/)

I would like to extend this code with PREV and NEXT "buttons" which do exactly as is... So if DIV2 currently visible and hit the next button the jump to the DIV3...

Is it possible with CSS+HTML only?

```css
#content > div {
  display: none;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#content > div:target {
  display: block;
}
#content > div a.hide {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#div1">Div one</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#div2">Div two</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#div3">Div three</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#div4">Div four</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">hide</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="content">
  <div id="div1">This is div one</div>
  <div id="div2">This is div two</div>
  <div id="div3">This is div three</div>
  <div id="div4">This is div four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need Javascript to listen events like click and manipulate your document dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
ul{
text-align: center;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto 20px;
}
li{
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid green;
padding: 10px;
}
#content{
position: relative;
max-width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.prev, .next, .dummy-right, .dummy-left{
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1px solid blue;
padding: 10px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
height: 40px;
width: 30px;
}
.prev, .dummy-left{
left: -30px;
}
.next, .dummy-right{
right: -30px;
}
.dummy-right, .dummy-left{
background: #fff;
border-color: #fff;
}
#content > div {
  display: none;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
#content > div:target {
  display: block;
}
#content > div a.hide {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#div1">Div one</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#div2">Div two</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#div3">Div three</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#div4">Div four</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">hide</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="content">

<a href="#div2" class="next">&gt;</a>        
  <div id="div1">
  This is div one

<a href="#div2" class="next">&gt;</a>  
<span class="dummy-left"></span>
</div>
  <div id="div2">This is div two

<a href="#div1" class="prev">&lt;</a>  
<a href="#div3" class="next">&gt;</a>  
</div>
  <div id="div3">This is div three
<a href="#div2" class="prev">&lt;</a>  
<a href="#div4" class="next">&gt;</a>  
</div>
  <div id="div4">This is div four

<a href="#div3" class="prev">&lt;</a>  
<span class="dummy-right"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take help of JavaScript. Because you need to do this on click event.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this -

```css
#wrap, ul, li { height: 300px; }
#wrap, li { position: relative; width: 500px; }
#wrap
{
 margin: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: #ccc;
}
ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 2000px;
}

#a1:target ul { left: 0px; }
#a2:target ul { left: -500px; }
#a3:target ul { left: -1000px; }
#a4:target ul { left: -1500px; }

li {
 float: left; 
}
a{
 cursor: pointer;
 display: none;
 height: 64px;
 width: 30px;
 outline-width: 0px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 90px;
 z-index: 2;
 background: red;
}
a[class^="down"] { left: 10px; }
a[class^="up"] { right: 10px; }

:target .up2.default { display: none; }

.up2.default,
#a1:target .up2,
#a2:target .down1,
#a2:target .up3,
#a3:target .down2,
#a3:target .up4,
#a4:target .down3{ display: block; }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
 <div id="a1">
 <div id="a2">
 <div id="a3">
 <div id="a4">
 <!-- 1 -->
 <a href="#a2" class="up2 default">2</a>
 <a href="#a2" class="up2">2</a>
 <!-- 2 -->
 <a href="#a1" class="down1">1</a>
 <a href="#a3" class="up3">3</a>
 <!-- 3 -->
 <a href="#a2" class="down2">2</a>
 <a href="#a4" class="up4">4</a>
 <!-- 4 -->
 <a href="#a3" class="down3">3</a>
  <ul>
   <li>
    00000
   </li> 
   <li>
    111111111111
   </li> 
   <li>
    2222222222 
   </li> 
   <li>
    444444
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div> <!-- End #a4 -->
 </div> <!-- End #a3 -->
 </div> <!-- End #a2 -->
 </div> <!-- End #a1 -->
</div>
```

Comment: You r a genius too, but afelixj answered first. Thank you anyway! Maddy and AfelixJ for president

Comment: to accept answer is not important, Important is you got the solution :-) and thanks for appreciation.